# retrieving the next element from tf.data.Dataset in tensorflow 2.0 beta

Tags: python, tensorflow, iterator, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

Before tensorflow 2.0-beta, to retrieve the first element from tf.data.Dataset, we may use a iterator as shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tensorflow as tf

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
iterator = train_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # 1.0 will be printed.
    print (sess.run(iterator.get_next()))
```

In tensorflow 2.0-beta, it seems that the above **one-shot-iterator** is now deprecated. To print out the entire elements we may use the following **for** approach.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tensorflow as tf

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])

for data in train_dataset:
    # 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, and 4.0 will be printed.
    print (data.numpy())
```

However, if we only want to retrieve exactly one element from tf.data.Dataset, then how can we do with tensorflow 2.0 beta? It seems that `next(train_dataset)` is not supported. It could be done easily with the old one shot iterator as shown above, but it's not very obvious with the new **for** based approach.

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: How about: `elem = list(train_dataset)[0]`.

Comment: @tidy your suggestion does not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can `.take(1)` from the dataset:

```py
for elem in train_dataset.take(1):
  print (elem.numpy())
```

Comment: This works but can we also do this without the `for elem in dataset' construct?

Comment: yeah - Flamefire's answer is better!

Answer (score 15):

What works with eager execution enabled (default in TF 2.0) is:

```
elem = next(iter(train_dataset))
```

Explanation: Datasets have an `__iter__` member function to support the `for elem in dataset:` approach. This returns an iterator. The Python function `iter` does just that: Basically calls the `__iter__` function. `next` then returns the first element that iterator produces.

I haven't found a solution which works for non-eager execution though, as that currently raises `RuntimeError: __iter__() is only supported inside of tf.function or when eager execution is enabled.`

Answer (score 1):

You can also convert the train.Dataset into a numpy iterator then use next().

```
np_iter = train_dataset.as_numpy_iterator()
print(np_iter.next())
```

Here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset.